# ildasm on Linux: "original" ildasm.exe same as dotnet-ildasm?

Tags: linux, .net

I would like to use ildasm on Linux. The original one, that comes with the .NET SDK and can be found on Windows e.g. at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\`.

I found [dotnet-ildasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ildasm/) and managed to install it on my Ubuntu 18.04. But I am unsure if this is the same as the "original" one.

- Is dotnet-ildasm the same as Microsoft ildasm?
- Did someone mangage to install the Microsoft ildasm on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original one was a native executable and this one is build in .NET by [utilizing](https://github.com/pjbgf/dotnet-ildasm/blob/master/src/dotnet-ildasm/dotnet-ildasm.csproj#L23) a [Mono.Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) library to get the assembly information so if I would have to answer your first question I would answer - no, they are not the same.

Not sure about your second question as original one was Windows executable so there's no point installing it on Linux. I would use the one you linked dotnet-ildasm or [ikdasm](https://github.com/mono/ikdasm) from the Mono project.

Why are you so focused on having the "original" one?

Comment: I am focussed in the original one because it would tell me if an assembly is obfuscated. This worked well for unknown obfuscators.

Comment: Out of curiosity. How did ildasm told you that assembly is obfuscated or not?

Comment: It says “protected module — cannot disassemble”

Comment: thx but "protected module" message is far from being obfuscated. It's just one [attribute added](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2007/12/05/preventing-ildasm-from-disassembling-your-assembly/). I can provoke the same on `ildasm` on a simple Hello World.

Comment: Ah interesting. Good point.

Comment: Then the other ildasm or ikdasm should be as good as the “original”